# What is the most flexible data type in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am experimenting with a possible data structure for an app of mine, and I need to provision a column in one of my SQL Server data tables to hold various data of unpredictable size.

Literally, this could mean a string of text, or a Base64 encoded video clip and everything in between.

I realize that the instant response is going to be that I should provision different tables for different types -- and I don't disagree -- but please humor me here.

```
varchar(MAX)?  
nvarchar(MAX)?
```

I am not a DBA so I don't know what type gives me the most flexibility for the lowest storage cost.

Comment: textual data and a base-64 encoded video clip are both strings, just of varying length. Do you want to store *other* types of data (in native format)?

Comment: At the moment, I can't imagine that I would ever need to store anything other that an extremely long string of text.  Any media can be encoded in Base64 format, correct?  Are you thinking that I may need to store bytes?  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: For storing Base64 encoded string VARCHAR(MAX) should do. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397624/which-sql-data-type-to-store-base64-encoded-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VARBINARY(MAX)?

In principle, trying to force multiple different data types into a single type is a bad idea.  You may be better served with a different table for each type. But if you're never going to search the field, you should be able to do anything with a binary field...

Comment: Thanks Dems!  I am reading up on this datatype now (want to be prudent for the sake of other SO users before selecting this as the winning answer).  Off the top of your head, do you know how much data this type takes vs. other MAX types?  Or does it even matter these days since storage is so cheap?  I know we aren't supposed to solicit opinions, but yours would really be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Object size + 2 bytes, I think.  And no, I would not worry about the differences in space use. Choose the correct type, don't compromise to make a barely perceptible optimisation that you'll nearly never need.

Comment: Great advice!  Thanks to all who posted but this answer seems to be the winner.  Thanks again Dems!!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `xml` datatype. It will permit you to store, query and index arbitrary XML documents.

Comment: Can that allow binary objects to be stored in the XML?

Comment: Thank you John!  I am checking the answers in chronological order.  I wouldn't have thought of XML.  Interesting. . .

Comment: @Dems: yes, you can store binary as base64 within the XML