# How to store a X509Certificate2 in db c#

Tags: c#, xml, ado.net, cryptography, x509certificate

Here is the scenario:

I have several `.pfx` files and I need to store them in a MySQL DB.

I already tried to store the RawData thing, but when I try to sign a xml using the reconstructed certificate I get:

> Signing key is not loaded.

Well so I tried to store the private key, using the function `ToXmlString` to generate a string from the private key and `FromXmlString` to load the new string, but then I get:

> Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided.

The point is, how to correctly store the certificate and its keys in the DB in a way that I can reconstruct it and use it for digital signing documents?

**Update:**

Already tried this and didn't work:
[Store an X509Certificate2 in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240176/store-an-x509certificate2-in-db)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificate only includes the *public* key, so storing only that won't work.

On the other hand, `cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true)` should work. Are you sure that you remembered to call it with the `includePrivateParameters` argument set to true and that you imported it as exportable?

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("key.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
string xml = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
```

Alternatively, you could just store the entire pfx in the database.

Comment: it gave me an error trying set the private parameters to true.How to store the whole pfx? serialize it? it doesn´t loose the keys... properties and etc?

Comment: @AlanAraya: I would just store the raw contents of the pfx file. Alternatively, check the way you imported the pfx file (see the edited answer).

Comment: Yeah thanks Faber.....it was missing the X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable parameter.....Don´t know, but withought it just don´t work...