# how to deal with x509 certificates and a centralized keystore programmatically?

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate

I'm developing a WCF application that should be able to deal with x509 certificates. In the final setup several instances of the application will exist on different servers and therefore the idea was to use a centralized store. So far I only know the Certificate stores that are either User or Machine specific and relatively easy to access programmatically, with the drawback that they are bound to one server/pc.
So is there an easy way to have some kind of centralized store and access it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the certificates in a database which is accessible by all servers. The exact way on how to do it is described in several questions on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334951/how-to-store-a-x509certificate2-in-db-c-sharp))

You'll need to implement some additional security, of course (i.e. store the certificates encrypted or at least use an SSL-protected DB connection), but overall this is manageable.

Comment: hm, I was looking for something like the X509Store, with StoreLocation.ExternalServer... by any chance, can Active Directory be abused to accomplish that

Comment: No, you can only distribute certificates to local stores by AD group policies.